# Can we override wsa:To value in SOAP 1.2

Tags: soap

I want to override `wsa:To` element value in SOAP 1.2 message. Can I do this by adding "`To" HTTP header` to the request ?

Could you explain the use of this `wsa:To` element value on the SOAP 1.2 message header ?

Answer (score 0):

No. `wsa:To` is a SOAP header block, not an HTTP header.